# How to use SQL to concatenate two rows with grouping and CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, string-concatenation

I have some genomic data that is in SQL Server 2016 Express and it is currently shaped in a long format with a reference genome and test genomes split by a `SubjectID`, genes, and codons (e.g. a 3-tuple).

What I really need is to reshape my data into one which the tuples are concatenated together but ONLY when there is a mutation (as compared to the reference genome) in the tuple.  This will be a more usable format for everyone.

My data looks like this

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE 
(
     SubjectID VARCHAR(MAX), 
     country VARCHAR(MAX), 
     gene VARCHAR(MAX), 
     position INT, 
     ReferenceNucleotide VARCHAR(1), 
     TestNucleotide VARCHAR(1), 
     codon INT, 
     nucleotide_order INT 
)

INSERT INTO @myTable 
VALUES
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   65,'A','x', 92,1),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   66,'T','x', 92,2),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   67,'C','C', 92,3),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   68,'T','T', 93,1),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   69,'A','A', 93,2),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   70,'C','C', 93,3),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   71,'G','G', 94,1),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   72,'A','A', 94,2),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   73,'C','C', 94,3),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   74,'A','A', 95,1),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   75,'G','C', 95,2),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   76,'C','C', 95,3),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   77,'C','C', 96,1),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   78,'T','T', 96,2),
('1-0002','India','gyrA',   79,'G','N', 96,3)
```

However, there are a couple of conditions

- If all three nucleotides are the same for the reference and test genome I want a 'WT'
- If there is any difference in nucleotides, I want the 3-tuple from the test genome (in the nucleotide order)
- I need to group by SubjectID and gene because I have lots of Subjects & genes

And my result would look like

```
1-0002 India gyrA 92 xxC
1-0002 India gyrA 93 WT
1-0002 India gyrA 94 WT
1-0002 India gyrA 95 ACC
1-0002 India gyrA 96 CTN
```

I can identify where the codons are that need to have the 3-tuple but am struggling with how to concatentate them

```
DECLARE @myCodons TABLE (SubjectID varchar(max), country varchar(max), gene  varchar(max), codon int, WT int)

INSERT INTO @myCodons
    SELECT 
        SubjectID, country, gene, codon,
        SUM(CASE WHEN RefNucleotide=TestNucleotide THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS WT
    FROM 
        @myTable
    GROUP BY 
        SubjectID, country, gene, codon 

SELECT * 
FROM @myCodons 
ORDER BY codon
```

Comment: What are nucleotides  here?

Comment: the nucleotides are the 'A', 'G', 'C', and 'T' s the order they are placed in is first by codon( in this example 92 thru 96), then nucleotide_order  (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with something like:

```
select T1.SubjectID, T1.country, T1.gene, T1.codon, 
    T1.RefGenome + T2.RefGenome + T3.RefGenome RefGenome,
    T1.TestGenome + T2.TestGenome + T3.TestGenome TestGenome
from @myTable T1
    inner join @myTable T2 on T1.SubjectID = T2.SubjectID and T1.country = T2.country
        and T1.gene = T2.gene and T1.codon = T2.codon and T2.nucleotide_order = 2
    inner join @myTable T3 on T1.SubjectID = T3.SubjectID and T1.country = T3.country
        and T1.gene = T3.gene and T1.codon = T3.codon and T3.nucleotide_order = 3
where T1.nucleotide_order = 1
```

You can then build on this with case statements to work out whether to display the test genome or 'WT'

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach which might be of use:

```
select SubjectID, country, gene, codon, case when RefGenomeStr = TestGenomeStr then 'WT' else TestGenomeStr end wanted_string
from @myTable t1
cross apply(
    SELECT
        STUFF((
              SELECT
                    ', ' +RefGenome
              FROM @myTable t2
              WHERE t2.SubjectID= t1.SubjectID and t2.country = t1.country and  t2.gene = t1.gene and t2.codon = t1.codon
              FOR XML PATH ('')
              )
             , 1, 1, '')
      , STUFF((
              SELECT
                    ', ' +TestGenome
              FROM @myTable t2
              WHERE t2.SubjectID= t1.SubjectID and t2.country = t1.country and  t2.gene = t1.gene and t2.codon = t1.codon
              FOR XML PATH ('')
              )
             , 1, 1, '')
         ) ca (RefGenomeStr,TestGenomeStr)    
where nucleotide_order = 1
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------+---------+------+-------+---------------+
|    | SubjectID | country | gene | codon | wanted_string |
+----+-----------+---------+------+-------+---------------+
|  1 | 1-0002    | India   | gyrA |    92 |  x, x, C      |
|  2 | 1-0002    | India   | gyrA |    93 | WT            |
|  3 | 1-0002    | India   | gyrA |    94 | WT            |
|  4 | 1-0002    | India   | gyrA |    95 |  A, C, C      |
|  5 | 1-0002    | India   | gyrA |    96 |  C, T, N      |
+----+-----------+---------+------+-------+---------------+
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/OID7510)